# IOS UIController hierarchy and memory use

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller

Have general question about IOS Controllers:

On start ios created default UI View Controller and then I can call presentViewController or use Segue to open others

Question is if previous controllers are still in memory?

For example here is chain:  A->B->C->D->B->C.... and so on, transition B->C->D->B is in cycle.

Will it create new instance of each controller and keep each copy? will it reuse?

thanks

Comment: Except for unwind segues, segues always instantiate new controllers. This is a very important point to understand about segues. You should not go backwards (to controllers you've already put on screen) with segues unless you use an unwind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, if you are doing modal segues and presentViewController calls the ViewControllers still exist. Rather than segueing to new instances of these viewControllers that you've already created, your should call `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];` and dismiss down the stack to get back to the viewController you've already created.

You can use the `presentingViewController` property like:

```
[[[self presentingViewController]presentingViewController]dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]...etc
```

or

`[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];` (if you're using nav VC's)

in order to quickly dismiss down several viewControllers.
`viewDidLoad` will not be called again but you can refresh your viewController inside of `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear`.